# Selecting Account Numbers with latest date

Tags: sql, select, join, subquery

I have been trying to solve this problem now for days.
I have table called Stat with the following simplified structure and sample data:

```
Customer    BankID  AccNumb Type                Date        Amount    AccType

Customer 1  Boa     5       Account Statement   2015-01-01  10000,00    Eur
Customer 1  CS      10      Account Statement   2015-04-04  22000,00    Eur
Customer 2  Sa      15      Account Statement   2015-03-13  3000,00     Eur
Customer 2  Sa      40      Account Statement   2015-04-24  1000,00     Eur
Customer 2  Sa      15      Sale Advice         2015-04-16  400,00      Eur
Customer 2  Sa      15      Account Statement   2015-12-24  50,00       Usd
Customer 2  Boa     20      Sale Advice         2015-05-15  6000,00     Eur
Customer 3  Cu      25      Account Statement   2015-11-27  81000,00    Eur
Customer 3  Cu      30      Sale Advice         2015-11-27  3000,00     Usd
Customer 3  Pop     30      Account Statement   2015-11-27  12000,00    Eur
```

What I'm trying to do is to Select the AccountNumber with the latest date specified. A Customer can also have different Account Numbers on various Banks, so it should also be grouped by BankID and Customer.

I have come this far:

```
SELECT AccNumb, Customer, BankID,
(SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM Stat 
        WHERE AccNumb = y.AccNumb AND Customer = y.Customer AND 
              BankID = y.BankID AND Type = 'Account Statement' AND 
              Date = MAX(y.Date) GROUP BY Amount) Amount
FROM Stat y
    GROUP BY AccNumb, Customer, BankID
        ORDER BY Customer, AccNumb
```

And it works fine, the problem is i should also add the column AccType and Date
I managed to do this with 2 more subselects (the query takes long but it works).

But now i have the problem that there are also NULL values in Customer (or Date) Column. Now, the account number of these 'NULL' Customers still should be displayed if it's the latest date. I also tried to do the same by joining the table by itself, and it didnt work out.

```
SELECT x.AccNumber, x.Customer, x.BankID, x.Date, y.Amount, y.AccType
FROM Stat y RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT AccNumber, Customer, BankID, MAX(Date) Date  FROM Stat 
        GROUP BY AccNumber, Customer, BankID) x 
 ON x.AccNumber = y.AccNumber AND 
    x.Customer = y.Customer AND 
    x.BankID = y.BankID AND 
    x.Date = y.Date
ORDER BY y.Customer, y.AccNumber
```

But now the 'NULL' Customers only have NULL values in the Amount, Date and AccType Columns, which is not correct.

The output should be something like this

```
AccNumb     Customer        BankID  Amount  Date        AccType

111111111   a               Boa     1234.40 31.06.2014  Eur
222222222   NULL            Boa     5678.40 31.04.2014  Eur
333333333   b               Boa     0.00    25.02.2014  Eur
444444444   NULL            Boa     9101.40 23.04.2015  Eur
555555555   NULL            Boa     1213.40 31.02.2014  Usd
A66666666   c               Sa      NULL    31.02.2014  Eur
777777777   c               Sa      1415.00 31.12.2014  Eur
888888888   c               Boa     1617.40 31.12.2014  Usd
999999999   f               Pop     5678.64 31.10.2014  Eur
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `row_number()`, if I understand correctly:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, bankId order by date desc) as seqnum
      from stat s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: wow! this seems to work(with partitioning by accnumb also), the only problem is i get a duplicate AccountNumber for Customers having also 'NULL'  as Customer Name

Comment: I had to partition by bankId and Accnumb only :-) works now perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Find the rows with latest dates, i.e. return a row if no other row with same AccountNumber, BankID and Customer but a later Date exists:

```
select *
from stat s1
where not exists (select 1 from stat s2
                  where s1.AccountNumber = s2.AccountNumber
                    and s1.BankID = s2.BankID
                    and s1.Customer = s2.Customer
                    and s1.Date < s2.Date)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you i just tried this. 
But I have to group it by AccountNumber, Bankid and Customer so after that i cannot add the other columns anymore. (There shouldn't be duplicate AccountNumbers in the result)

Comment: Can't you show us the wanted result? Maybe I missed something, but my query reflects how I read your description.

Comment: I have added the results now

Answer (score 0):

You're first query works closely to what, I believe, you are looking for. Using it as a base, we can alter to work for you:

```
SELECT 
    AccNumb, 
    Customer, 
    BankID,
    Amount,
    Date,
    AccType
FROM Stat y
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(z.DATE) 
              FROM Stat z 
              WHERE z.AccNumb = y.AccNumb 
                AND z.Customer = y.Customer 
                AND z.BankID = y.BankID AND Type = 'Account Statement')
ORDER BY Customer, AccNumb
```